# C# Sqltimeout command don't know program side or sql server side

Tags: c#, sql-server, timeout, timeoutexception

I have a c# program that connects to sql server and get data.
This part of program that connects to sql has lots of classes and inheritance that is not written by me and
I've never managed to get sqltimeout exceptions from that, which connects to sql server and receives data.

But I have to restart my program and sql timeouts is gone. I don't know is it sql part that locks in storedprocedures
or my program locking?

this is the error:

> System.Exception: Error In Process 'dbsource' Command In Sequence 1:
>   Error In Run 'dbsource' Command: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   (0x80131904): Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to
>   completion of the operation or the server is not responding. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation
>   timed out 
>       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) 
>       at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)

This is some part of sqlconnection class named dbsource:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(setting.ConnectionString))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SET ARITHABORT ON", con))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                command.CommandText = base.HtmlCommand.Attributes["procedurename"];
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(setting.ProcedureName))
                                {
                                    command.CommandText = HtmlCommand.HttpContext.CurrentSetting.DEFAULT_ProcedureName;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    command.CommandText = setting.ProcedureName;
                                }
                            }

                            var paramsNode = HtmlCommand.TagElements.SingleOrDefault(x => x.TagName == "params");
                            var nameValuePairTblParam = new System.Data.DataTable();
                            nameValuePairTblParam.Columns.Add("name");
                            nameValuePairTblParam.Columns.Add("Value");
                            if (paramsNode != null)
                            {
                                foreach (var node in paramsNode.TagElements)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        nameValuePairTblParam.Rows.Add(node.GetAttributeValue("name"), node.GetAttributeValue("value", true));
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
                                        throw new Exception("Error in Read Params Section!", ex);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            HtmlCommand.WriteOuterHtml(sb, "params");
                            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@c", sb.ToString()));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@x", HtmlCommand.HttpContext.Request.DomainId));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@y", nameValuePairTblParam));

                            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                            {                                
                                    adapter.Fill(dataSet);                                                               
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

There is a RenderingWrapper method that manages sqlConnctions in parallel manner:

```
private void RenderingWrapper(bool async)
        {
WaitToLoadAllPendingSource(Core, true);
}

protected void WaitToLoadAllPendingSource(string core, bool forIfAttrOnly)
        {
            CheckDataSourcePending(forIfAttrOnly);
            DataSourceAdded();
            if (PendingSource.Count != 0)
            {
                if (OwnerGroup.AllSourceLoaded)
                {
#if DEBUG
                    Util.Log(string.Format("{0:000#} - {1} Stop Process For Not Exist Datasource '{2}' Without Wait...", ID, core, string.Join("','", PendingSource)), ConsoleColor.Red);
#endif
                    return;
                }
#if DEBUG
                Util.Log(string.Format("{0:000#} - {1} Wait Start For '{2}'...", ID, core, string.Join("','", PendingSource)), ConsoleColor.DarkCyan);
#endif
                _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
                Thread process = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    while (_waitHandle != null)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1);
                        CheckDataSourcePending(forIfAttrOnly);
                        DataSourceAdded();
                    }
                });

                process.Start();
                _waitHandle.WaitOne(Parent.HttpContext.CurrentSetting.DEFAULT_ExecuteCMSCommandWaitTimeout);
                _waitHandle.Dispose();
                _waitHandle = null;
#if DEBUG
                Util.Log(string.Format("{0:000#} - {1} Wait End.", ID, core), ConsoleColor.DarkCyan);
#endif
                CheckDataSourcePending(forIfAttrOnly);
                DataSourceAdded();
            }
        }

public virtual void DataSourceAdded()
        {
            lock (_check_data_source_lock)
            {

                if (PendingSource != null)
                {
                    foreach (var pendingSource in PendingSource.ToArray())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            OwnerGroup.GetSource(pendingSource);
                            //check if null
                            //if added by reza
                            if (PendingSource != null)
                                PendingSource.Remove(pendingSource);
                        }
                        catch {/*Nothing*/}
                    }
                }

                if (PendingSource == null || PendingSource.Count == 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (_waitHandle != null)
                        {
                            _waitHandle.Set();
                        }
                    }
                    catch { /*Nothing*/}
                }
            }
        }


public override void CheckDataSourcePending(bool forIfAttrOnly)
        {
            if (Attributes != null)
            {
                if (forIfAttrOnly)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var value = Attributes["filter"];
                        Attributes["filter"] = InitalizeStringFromSource(value);
                    }
                    catch {/*Nothing*/ }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var key in Attributes.Keys.ToArray())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var value = Attributes[key];
                            Attributes[key] = InitalizeStringFromSource(value);
                        }
                        catch { /*Nothing*/}
                    }
                }
            }
            if (Elements != null && !forIfAttrOnly)
            {
                foreach (HtmlElement child in Elements)
                {
                    child.CheckDataSourcePending(false);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: With MS Profiler check if your sp is complete or not

Comment: @MazaherBazari It's under heavy load and there are a lot of clients conencted to it. We can not wait during time out and analyze the program

Comment: To answer your question asked in the title, command timeouts are enforced on the client, where the client API cancels the running query when it has exceeded the specified `CommandTimeout` (30 seconds by default). I suggest query and index tuning as first steps.

Comment: @DanGuzman Is it completely sql server side? SQL programmer resist that it's not SQL fault,and says because when you restart your exe, timeouts are gone, and your program locks sql resources and stored procedures, because of huge multitask connections

Comment: @Hamed_gibago, do you see a lot of blocking during the problem? Examine the query plans for scans.

Comment: @DanGuzman Do you mean SQL profiler?I think that programmer check query plans. I don't know‚ if there would not be lots of query planning is there c# program side?

Comment: Not profiler, use a tool like SSMS or Azure Data Studio. Run the proc from an ssms query window with the Include Actual Execution plan option (from the Query menu). Look for scan operators specifically.

Comment: @DanGuzman Does query plans in SSMS help? because timeout sometimes happens.

Comment: @Hamed_gibago, query and index tuning is the first step to avoid timeouts. That will allow the SQL Server to handle more concurrent queries as well as avoid blocking and deadlocking. If you still get timeouts after that, check sql server activity during the problem to see if it's due to blocking or other reason.

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks for helping me.I would check query plannig. Is there any way to send pictures from query plans here?

Comment: @Hamed_gibago, for query plans, upload the actual plan xml [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question.